# Highlight letter individually else revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag

In my word game I have got a style that shows the user which word to drag and drop the letters on to in order to complete.

It then allows the user to drop letters into that area but doesn't restrict the user from putting the letters anywhere else I need it so the user can only put the first letter into the first cell of the styled area.

Here is the code that applies the style to the given word with a click of a button (#picknext)...

```
$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
rndWord = shuffledWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.8 - Math.random();
})[0];
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + rndWord + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});
```

Ideally I would like the letters to revert if they are not dropped in the correct position.

I have some additional code that i have applied for a revert function on the letters already, hope it helps...

```
$('.drag').draggable({

helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: function(droppable) {
    if (droppable === false) {
        return true;
    }

    else {

        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Your shuffle technique is [flawed](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html).  You might want to look at the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking here.  What is the question

Comment: The question is how do I make the letters revert if they are not dropped in the designated area (.spellword)? @Scott Sauyet

Comment: Do you have a sample of your partially working code?  I am not picturing your application, and have no real mental model of what you mean by "revert".  Do you animate some draggable DIVs back to some previous location?  Do you just remove them and place them back in correct alphabetic order in some list?  Something else?